# Regex and Like operator in LinqToObjects

Tags: c#, regex, linq-to-objects

Just to avoid confusion I am talking about linq to object and nothing else.
I am working with lots objects in memory and I need to filter them.
we have a screen with lots of options where a user can select many values.

I need to implement something similar to the "Like" operator in sql.
I did found a post about it in this site and uses regex but I have never used it.
I want to know if my string pattern is correct.Should not use "%" "%"?

I have also read that you should use a combination of startWith -endWith and contains,but I have not found any examples that uses all the them combined,just to get a feel how to do it.

I do something like this

```
string pattern = string.Format(".*{0}.*", criteria.SearchText);
myList= myList.Where(x => x.Message.Like(pattern)).ToList();

public static bool Like(this string s, string pattern, RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
{
    return Regex.IsMatch(s, pattern, options);
}
```

Any suggestions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to check if a string contains another you can use:

```
myList = myList.Where(x => x.Message.Contains(criteria.SearchText)).ToList();
```

or

```
myList = myList.Where(x => x.Message.IndexOf(criteria.SearchText) != -1).ToList();
```

(the second variant is good because with `IndexOf` you can specify the `CultureInfo`)

If you want to mix a user-defined word in a `Regex` you should use the `Regex.Escape()` to escape it, so that if the user writes `a*`, the searched text is `a*` instead of `any number of a`.

```
string pattern = string.Format(".*{0}.*", Regex.Escape(criteria.SearchText));
```

But note that as written, it's equivalent to:

```
string pattern = string.Format("{0}", Regex.Escape(criteria.SearchText));
```

because you haven't put anchors to your regex, so the regex will be searched anywhere in the string.

If you want to anchor the user-defined word, so for example you want to search for words that begin with

```
string pattern = string.Format("^{0}", Regex.Escape(criteria.SearchText));
```

or end with

```
string pattern = string.Format("{0}$", Regex.Escape(criteria.SearchText));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot starting to make sense